# Global minimizer of discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Consider a function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ defined as
\begin{equation}
f(x) :=  \begin{cases}
x \quad  \text{ if }  x \neq 1-\frac{1}{k}, \text{ for integer } k \geq 2  \\
\frac{1}{k} \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I have couple of confusions.

- I am a little confused about the uniqueness of the minimizer. It is clear that $x=0$ is a global minimizer and the minimum value $f(0) = 0$. 
  Is this minimizer considered unique? The value $f(1-\frac{1}{k})$ converges to $f(0) = 0$ as $k \to \infty$. But $f(1) \neq 0$. What am I missing here? probably something related to definitions?
- The set $[0,1]$ is clearly compact. Does this mean that $\inf_{x\in[0,1]} f(x) = \min_{x\in[0,1]} f(x) = 0$ (The infimum exists?). Fix arbitrary small $\epsilon>0$; is the difference $\displaystyle \left\{\left(\inf_{x\in[\epsilon,1]} f(x)\right) - f(0)\right\}$ > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x\ne0$. The minimum is attained only at $x=0$, so $x=0$ is the unique global minimizer.

For the second question, take into account that $f$ is not continuous. Even if its domain is compact, it may not have a minimum (this is not the case in this example.) And for any $\epsilon>0$, we have 
$$
\inf_{\epsilon\le x\le1}f(x)=0,
$$
since $1-1/k>\epsilon$ for all $k$ large enough. But the infimum is not reached on $[\epsilon,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So we should  replace $\inf$ by $\min$ if $f$ is continuous? Do you maybe have an example for the case where $f$ doesn't have a minimum even when the domain is compact?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on a compact set, the infimum is the minimum. Here is an example: $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$, $f(0)=1$, $f(x)=x$ if $x\ne0$. The infimum is $0$, but $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.